# why jetty could not resolve some path, but tomcat could

Tags: tomcat, eclipse-plugin, jetty

start a web project in eclipse, first start it use tomcat , it could be started successfully, then use jetty plugin to start it, met below exception

```
Caused by: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]
```

Solution

```
<param-value>classpath*:/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
```

So why tomcat could resolve this path -- `/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml` correctly, but jetty not?

Comment: Which versions of Jetty and Tomcat? What "jetty plugin"? Which version of it?

Comment: What component is loading that resource? Tomcat doesn't recognize a path with a prefix `classpath*:`, so it must be something else.

Comment: @nitind `apache-tomcat-8.0.30` `Jetty Version: 8.1.14.v20131031` `http://eclipse-jetty.github.io/`